# Can a new node with new contract code join Corda network on the fly?

Tags: distributed-system, corda

Is it possible to create a new node with new set of contract code (jar) and join it to an existing Corda network and make it cooperate with the already existing nodes?

What are the steps for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as of V2, Corda supports this already. You just need to point the new node to the network map node of the network you wish to join. The nodes already on the network will need the CorDapp JAR for them to be able to use the cordapp running on the new node. The systems admins for those nodes will need to manually copy the JAR to the `/plugins` folder for their nodes.

In future versions, the the bytecode for all state types (and their associated contracts) referenced in transactions will be included in the transaction. Shared flows can also be attached to the transaction. Most flows are likely to have private implementations, however. As such, this code won't be attached to transactions.

The result is that there are likely to be at least 2 JARs for each CorDapp: one containing the shared code that will be attached to transactions and another containing private implementations of flows.